# Simpler way to numerically sort an array of .json files got from fs.readdir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, fs

Is there some easier way to sort these? When I use readdir, it gives it in such a way that it goes 1, 10, 11, 12... 19, 2, 20, etc. This way goes through all of them and removes ".json" at the end, THEN sorts them numerically (which will work properly on numbers, not strings) and then adds the ".json" back to the end. Any better way to do this?

```
fs.readdir("data/items/", function(err,files) {
for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    files[i] = files[i].split(".")[0];
}
files = files.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    files[i] += ".json";
}

//load the files.. etc.

});
```

Comment: got an example of the filenames?

Comment: Provide a listing of all files in the `data/items` folder.

Comment: Your current example never sorts anything numerically. (need example of files names to be sure) but it seems like you have `0.json`, `1.json`,...`20.json`, etc. Your compare fn in the sort is comparing strings because you never cast the file prefixes to Numbers.

Comment: I have these files:
0.json
1.json
10.json
2.json
20.json
22.json
3.json

If I pull them straight from readdir, they're in that order. By reading the first "letter" and then the second if two match. However, using this my way, it returns as expected.

0.json
1.json
2.json
3.json
10.json
20.json
22.json
https://i.imgur.com/i5dnlao.png

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readdir("data/items/", function(err,files) {
  files.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.split(".")[0] - b.split(".")[0];
  });

  //load the files.. etc.
});
```

Should be enough, if you trust files are all well named.

The [sort method sorts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in place. And there is no need to separate out all the prefixes before sorting and then reattach, the compare function can keep that logic in isolation and the `files` var always remains a list of file names.